# Closing iAD Banner causes the current scene to change

Tags: swift, iad

I implemented `iAD`, which shows a Banner on the bottom of the screen. I call a function, `showsAD()` in my `Menu` class and `GameScene` class to show the banner. `GameScene` is where all the gameplay happens. If I click on `iAd Banner` in `GameScene`, it automatically switches the scene back to `Menu` for some reason. With some online resources, this the code I used to show `iAd Banner`, which is in `GameViewContorller`:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {
    var SH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
    var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "hideBannerAd", name: "hideadsID", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showBannerAd", name: "showadsID", object: nil)

    self.UIiAd.hidden = true
    self.UIiAd.alpha = 0
    }

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let BV = UIiAd.bounds.height
    UIiAd.delegate = self
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH + BV, 0, 0)
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    UIiAd.delegate = nil
    UIiAd.removeFromSuperview()
}


func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    _ = UIiAd.bounds.height
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.01) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.alpha = 1 // Fade in the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.01)
    UIiAd.alpha = 0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func showBannerAd() {
    UIiAd.hidden = false
    let BV = UIiAd.bounds.height

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.01) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH - BV, 0, 0) // End position of the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()

}

func hideBannerAd() {
    UIiAd.hidden = true
    let BV = UIiAd.bounds.height

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.01) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH + BV, 0, 0) // End position of the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Then in `GameScene` and `Menu` class, this is what I use to show the `iAD Banner`:

```
func showAds(){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showadsID", object: nil)
}
```

I tried pausing, but didn't work. Here's the code:

```
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        print("Clicked")

        iAdBanner.delegate = self
        // If you want to pause game scene:
        let skView: SKView = self.view as! SKView!
        skView.scene!.paused = true

        return true
    }
    func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        print("Closed")

        // If you want to continue game scene:
        let skView: SKView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.scene!.paused = false
    }
```

Comment: Where are the rest of your [ADBannerView delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/)? Could it be that you are not pausing your game play once the `ADBannerView` is tapped? Check out `bannerViewActionShouldBegin(_ banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool`.

Comment: @DanielStorm I added those methods, but they wouldn't pause the game play. I have updated my method to what they are.

Comment: @duskwuff thanks for letting me know. What is alternte now that iAd has gone away?

Comment: @duskwuff actually, it seems that the Apple side of selling ads is the only thing shutting down. Not iAd itself, https://twitter.com/bzamayo/status/688142655545454592

Comment: @DanielStorm Huh, okay. That's… confusing. Sources do suggest that iAd is winding down, but perhaps not as quickly as I thought. (I based my initial statement on [Daring Fireball's summary](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2016/01/15/iad), which seems to have been inaccurate.)

Comment: @duskwuff I've read a few different articles now and they all seem to be split on how they're interpreting Apple's statement. I'm guessing iAd will be like AdMob and Facebook once they're done transitioning meaning that iAd will become an open network for any advertiser.

Comment: What do you guys suggest then? I have just started developing apps and all this is getting me so confused. lol

Comment: @Sharukh check out [AdMob](https://www.google.com/admob/).